# Use custom model method in custom django queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-orm

A custom Model queryset takes one of the model's field to make some calculations, but now I need to get that field through a custom model method where I make some adjustment's according to the request.user's timezone. The function takes user as a parameter.

Here are some code snippets:

queryset:

```
break_time_start = F("machine_break_time__break_time_start")
```

model function:

```
def break_time_start_user(self, user) -> datetime.time:
    utc_time = self.break_time_start_utc.replace(tzinfo=self.timezone)
    date = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), utc_time)
    return localtime(date, user.timezone).time()
```

How can I use this custom method in my custom queryset?

Comment: Your method is executed in application space and queryset is on database level what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know that method is on app lvl and the qs is on DB lvl, but I somehow need to make that method available on DB lvl or somehow extract that method in my queryset. I don't think this is plausible or is it?

Comment: Method itself not, but if you try to explain exact problem someone could write you solution related to database level

Comment: Well, the problem is that, there are TimeFields in Postgres stored with user's timezone. In order for me to get that time value from DB and show it to other users I need to get that timefield value, convert it to utc and the convert it to the timezone of the user that is requesting this value